# access host store from library component with redux

Tags: redux

I am developing a package, I wish my component could access the store when it has been installed.
My package looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectCount, increment } from "./cardSlice";
import styles from "./Card.module.css";

export default function Card() {
  const count = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [incrementAmount, setIncrementAmount] = useState("2");

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.countblock}> {count}</div>
      <button
        className={styles.button}
        aria-label="Increment value"
        onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But got the following error

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

[image]

How can I fix it, and create a library that could access the store where it been installed?

My package

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "react-app"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel ./src/components -d dist --copy-files"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Do you have your react components tree (in final react application that uses your library) wrapped with `Provider` from `react-redux`?

Comment: Yes, sure, I use create-react-app --template redux. It helps me build redux store.

Comment: Ok, then my suspicious is that you are included `react-redux` library code in your library code. You should externalize it, when you are creating library package. Have you do it? If no, then your app is using 2 instances of `react-redux` one from library code and the other from your app dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I move my local package to remote, then it works. And I also move some libraries to devDependencies.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, gladly helped.

Comment: Hi lavor. My boss told me I should figure why this happened. 
Did you know how to externalize react-redux?

Comment: If you are using webpack, look at this section in the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash